# Причастный оборот

Tags: морфология

Здравствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста! При каких условиях придаточное определительное НЕЛЬЗЯ заменить обособленным определением, выраженным причастным оборотом?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос не странный. Вопрос из ЕГЭ. 
Придаточное определительное нельзя заменить причастным оборотом в следующих случаях:
 1. Союзное слово который стоит в косвенном падеже с предлогом.
 2. Сказуемое в придаточной части употреблено в форме будущего времени или сослагательного (условного) наклонения
 3. В главной части предложения есть указательное слово.
 Обычно этих условий достаточно. чтобы найти верный ответ, даже не пытаясь произвести замену. Редко, но встречаются случаи, когда ни одного из этих условий нет, но есть предложение(-я) просто со словом который в косвенном падеже без предлога. Тогда все-таки надо попробовать практически произвести замену и выбрать правильный ответ.

Comment: Умслопогас в дурдоме. ©
Это в учебниках такие формулировки?

Comment: В пособиях, рекомендованных ФИПИ. Как ни странно, следуя этим правилам, дети быстро находят нужный ответ. (Трудно что ли увидеть "В котором"?). А вот действительно правильно употребить причастие - далеко не все сумеют, т.к. причастие - форма книжной речи, а дети сегодняшние, как известно, почти не читают. Вот такое натаскивание на верный ответ!

Comment: Простите мою безграмотность. а что такое "Умслопогас"

Comment: Это из Ильфа и Петрова. То ли выдуманное, то ли подсмотренное сокращение некоей организации. Но явно наводит на мысль о "погашении мысли". В каковых целях и используется не одним поколением юмористов и журналистов.

Comment: Спасибо за напоминание, явно пора перечитывать.

Answer (score 0):

Странный вопрос... Всегда можно, если разрешается хоть чуть-чуть расширить или уточнить смысл. А если буква в букву... Да в массе случаев, когда грамматика не позволяет.

Вот два: а) когда нет подходящего причастия и б) когда определительное относится к дополнению НЕ в винительном падеже без предлога.

"Человек, которого я ранее любил" - "Человек, ранее любимый мною".
"Человек, которого я ранее знал" - "Человек, ранее (знаемый) мною". 
(Лопатин, правда, даёт форму "знаемый", но сомнительно.)
"Человек, которому я писал" - "Человек, ?"

Это всё, что приходит в голову. Может вопрос уточните?